# Image's aspect ratio on its container

Tags: html, css

I know there are similar questions, all of them are old, and I was wondering maybe there are newer techniques.

I have the following HTML:

```
<figure class="main-slider__slide">
<img class="main-slider__image" src="http://smth.com/a.jpg" alt="test">
</figure>
```

What I need is the `figure` container keeping the room for the `img` while it's not loaded yet. Without the container keeping the space I end up with twitching content which feels awful.

So far I've came up with the following SASS mixin:

```
@mixin image-placeholder($x,$y, $image-wrapper-class,$image-class) {
  .#{$image-wrapper-class} {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: percentage($y/$x);
  }

  .#{$image-class} {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

Being applied like `@include image-placeholder(1170, 405, main-slider__slide, main-slider__image);` it generates CSS like

```
.main-slider__slide {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 34.61538%; 
}

.main-slider__image {
  position: absolute; 
}
```

The problem is that I have to hardcore the size of my images in the styles and have a separate class for every image of with certain dimensions. Do you guys know better solutions where one general placeholder class would resolve the problem?

Comment: I don't think that is possible: the reason being that the aspect ratio of the image cannot be known until it is loaded, as it is inferred from the image's `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties. What you can do is to simply specify a common aspect ratio (most placeholder/wireframing uses a fixed aspect ratio for unknown content), which is adjusted when the image is loaded.

Comment: It sounds like you want the webpage to know the dimensions of images that have not been loaded yet. This is physically impossible.

Comment: I doubt that there is some generic solution is available because you still need to have information about dimensions (or aspect ratio) of the element before it will be loaded, but you want it to be only inside not-yet-loaded element.

Comment: Realistically this requires a back end approach - getting the image dimensions in the back end and writing them out in the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote into comment above - I doubt that there is general solution that will allow you to obtain information about not-yet-loaded element.

However it may be possible to mimic such behavior.

One thing that came in mind is to have tiny resized version of the image to be loaded to be inlined into document and then replaced by actual image upon page load. E.g. your 1170x405 image can be squeezed by 20x factor to 50x20 that will give you ~1kb of image size in jpeg. This image may be stored as `<img src="data:" class="image-placeholder">` directly into document and act as a temporary replacement for your actual image. You can scale it to original size using CSS and load original image either by JavaScript or by allowing browser to load it without displaying or by putting it immediately over placeholder. It can be also useful to apply `filter: blur(10px)` or something like this to image placeholder so it will not look ugly. Actually you can even animate this filter value to provide pleasant visual transition from scaled down placeholder towards original image.

I've used such approach into one of my projects and it was working well.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yeah I already use blurred low-quality images but they're not inlined into the doc directly. Good idea though.